# Is there a way to colorize a div's background image with CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I am using a large png sprite for icons within my application. These icons are all grey, and consist of transparent backgrounds. Is there a way that I can colorize them with CSS? I tried webkit filters, but that seems to only work with an img.

The HTML

```
<div class="icon iconPencil"></div>
```

The CSS

```
.icon {float:left;width:16px;height:16px;background: url('../../images/interface/icons_x2.png') no-repeat 0 0;background-size: 1424px 1424px;}
.icon.iconPencil {background-position:-96px -32px;}
```

[image: UI Example]

In the example above, I would like to colorize the cog icon, which is part of my sprite, and has a transparent background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use images then I would point to the answer by Sutherland about svgs using css tricks. If you want to use font icons then I would use http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ . All you have to do is copy and paste their link into your head and then you can use their list of icons. You can change the color of each icon like you would text on your website.

example of styling after adding link to the head of your html page:

```
/* CSS */

i.fa-cog {
color:#333;
}

<!-- HTML -->

<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
```

I have used font awesome icons in several projects and it is great.

Comment: I love this. I had it installed in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

you can't do this with png's you'll need to use svg's instead https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve what you want. Best to use the following css and font toolkit. Its very easy to use this library and its constantly updating with new icons.

http://fontawesome.io/

`<i class="fa fa-cog" style="color: red"></i> My Cog`

Here is a JSFidde-

http://jsfiddle.net/costh/nuLvr4ue/

Answer (score 0):

As Hayden and Charlie say, your best bet is to use icon fonts. But this is not limited to font awesome, you can use any Unicode

```css
div:before {
    content: '\2605';
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

You can look for unicode chars [here](http://shapecatcher.com/)